# Is there a plugin to block ads in Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

Is there any plugin to block ads in iPhone, iPad's Safari like [Ad Block Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) is available for Firefox (Desktop)?

Without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to block ads in mobile safari without a jailbreak or the use of an alternative browser from the app store.

Comment: More Generally, you can't add plugins to MobileSafari without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a free service called speedmeup (http://www.speedmeup.net/) which does not require to install an app. It works with wifi connections and will block ads inside apps, videos or music stream.

For your information, I am affiliated with the product but I think it works great.

If you like it, don't hesitate to drop us a message!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for disclosing your affiliation. Be sure to participate with questions that are not directly related to your product for the best reception from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Weblock - AdBlock for iOS on the App Store on iTunes https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/weblock-adblock-for-ios/id558818638?mt=8